# Proving an inequality with big O notation

Tags: inequality

I'm trying to prove that

$$\frac{2^{n}}{\sqrt{2^{n^{2}}-2^{n}}} = O\bigg(\frac{1}{2^{n^{2}-n}}\bigg)$$

The way I approach is it:

$$\frac{2^{n}}{\sqrt{2^{n^{2}}-2^{n}}} \leq \frac{2^{n}}{ \sqrt{ 2^{n^{2}}- \frac{2^{n^{2}}}{2} } } = O\bigg(\frac{1}{2^{n^{2}-n}}\bigg)$$

I am trying to be a little less sloppy for the last inequality.

Comment: I  don't think this is true : roughly, the denominator is like $2^{\frac {n^2}2}$, so the first fraction is like $\frac 1{2^{\frac {n^2}2 - n}}$, which is not a constant away from $\frac{1}{2^{n^2- n}}$, because the quotient is $2^{n^2/2}$ which goes to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. Denoting  the given expression by $A_n$ we see that $A_n \geq \frac {2^{n}} {{2^{n^{2}/2}}}$ since $2^{n^{2}} -2^{n} <2^{n^{2}}$. Hence $2^{n^{2}-n}A_n \geq 2^{n^{2}/2} \to \infty$.